# Need higher performance for three-way quick sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time, quicksort

I'm currently trying to implement a three partition quick sort. The below code works fine but does not run in sufficiently enough time. I'm new to data structures, algorithms, and "in depth" programming in general, so my attempts to fiddle around with it to get it to work in less time have largely come to nothing. (Memory performance is fine.)

My intuition is to alter the pivot, but I worry that it wouldn't be a three-way quick sort, then.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using std::vector;
using std::swap;


int partition3(vector<int> &a, int l, int r) {

    int x = a[l]; 
    int j = l;
    int k = r;
    int i = l+1; 

    while (i <= k) {
        if (a[i] < x) {
          swap(a[i],a[j]);
          j++; 
          i++;
        }
        else if(a[i] > x) {
            swap(a[i],a[k]);
            k--;
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    return j;
}

void randomized_quick_sort(vector<int> &a, int l, int r) {

    if (l >= r) {
        return;
    }

    int k = l + rand() % (r - l + 1);
    swap(a[l], a[k]);

    while (l < r) {
        int m = partition3(a, l, r);
        if ((m-l) < (r-m)) {
            randomized_quick_sort(a, l, m - 1);
            l = m + 1; 
        }
        else {
            randomized_quick_sort(a, m + 1, r);
            r = m - 1;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }
    randomized_quick_sort(a, 0, a.size() - 1);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

Comment: `rand()` could be taking some time. Does it need to be random? Can you find a faster random number generator?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you are measuring? IO will be slow and noisy. `rand()` is implementation dependent. Make sure you don't include them when you measure your speed.

Comment: It's for the grading system-I'm submitting this for testing online.

Comment: add quick custom random function [source](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/random_number.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically a code review (and you can't pick another site in the stack exchange network).

Answer (score 4):

Sorting is quite a complex problem in the real world. Try to look at some efficient implementations, e.g., those provided by implementations of C++ Standard Library. Explore web, read articles, look at discussions, ...

Just some notes:

1. Random number generation is (relatively) expensive, it can slow down quicksort significantly. (However, it can do the opposite for some kind of data as well.)
2. Integer division is (relatively) very expensive, likely more than random number generation.
3. Pure quicksort alone is rarely used in practice. Typically, it is combined with insertion sort, since recursive calls are inefficient for very small partitions (a threshold is usually set somewhere between 8 and 16 elements).
4. To prevent quicksort worst-case complexity, the level of recursion is typically checked and if it crosses some threshold (2 x log_2(n)), the rest of data is soreted with another algorithm (usually heapsort).

Etc...

**UPDATE**

Two more thoughts:

5. In multi-core/many-core environments, parallel algorithms will likely provide the best speedup for you. But to design a parallel quicksort is anything but easy. The most of the complexity falls on efficient parallel partitioning and load balancing. Libstdc++ Parallel Mode has a nice OpenMP implementation. Or, you can also check my AQsort: https://github.com/DanielLangr/AQsort.
6. To make quicksort more efficient, use *tail call elimination/optimization*. It considerably reduces the required call stack space.

Comment: The random pivots prevent worst-case complexity in practice, so don't do (4) unless you've changed (1) already. Assuming reasonable random numbers, the probability of the time being worse than some constant multiple of n log n is minuscule (i.e. no more probable than than things like GUID collision or cosmic ray interference with your machine). And the random pivot is easier to code than introsort...

Comment: Yes. I did a *lot* of online research on sorting yesterday. Hm... I think I'll try #3 first: use a different sort for test cases below a certain length threshold.

Comment: Then, note that you can run insertion sort only **once** at the very end of your algorithm. See, e.g., [Libstdc++-v3 source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L1968).

Comment: When you get your stuff working, you can compare performance to std::sort. std::sort (C++) is normally faster than classic C qsort, e.g. since comparison op is bound at compile time instead of using fcn ptrs.

Comment: @ErikAlapää It's not that this code doesn't work *per se*, it's that it breaks the time limit. But it is extremely interesting to see the difference between old C and C++ in things like that.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed. I also learned yesterday form Herb Sutter's blog that C++17 or a later standard will have support for STL algorithms that use manycore CPUs efficiently. https://isocpp.org/files/papers/P0024R2.html

Comment: [I have a multi-threaded partition algorithm on my github page](https://github.com/grahamreeds/parallel_partition)

Comment: @Anonymous: it's surprising that this breaks the time limit in an online judge. They're usually fairly generous, and this code looks basically fine to me, there's no major problems that should make it heinously slow (unless `rand()` or I/O is very slow in the judge environment). Is the challenge *intended* to be difficult to meet the time limit? If insertion-sorting small blocks doesn't solve the time problem then something strange is probably going on.

Comment: @DanielLangr: from experience, the peril with insertion-sorting the whole array at the end, is that it conceals any bugs in your quicksort :-)

Comment: @DanielLangr: to your point (6), the questioner has already done that, no? The recursive call handles the smaller partition and the loop handles the larger partition, ensuring O(log n) total stack use. Pushing (pointers to) blocks to be sorted into a data structure, to entirely avoid call recursion, is possible but I think it's a very marginal change compared with what's already done here.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, he has. I just wanted these hints to be "complete", more for other readers... As for insertion sort, I would prefer to check bugs via assertions or some conditionally-compiled code than to make my code less efficient ;)

Comment: @DanielLangr: sure, it's a matter of making sure that your unit tests of the smaller functions protect you from ending up with what amounts to a lot of futile faffing about followed by a quadratic-time insertion sort ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see here really solid code.

If you want to keep the algorithm, the best way to speed it up is changing it from recursive to iterative. It will not be a huge boost but it will help, each fucntion call is an overhead that is good to avoid. Manually swaping is also a good choice.

You can also gain some speed avoiding extra memory allocation, so you should try to reuse your variables as much as you can, for example, declare int m out of the while.

Comment: Thanks. This is for an assignment covering the divide and conquer paradigm, so I assume (I think) that there should be a way to pass while doing recursion. I'll keep that in mind, though: I'm starting to get pretty frustrated. I've got other things to do today.